# How long does it take for a galaxy (or other object) to disappear behind the cosmic sight horizon?

Tags: galaxy, universe, distances, redshift, observable-universe

After looking at [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14336/are-there-any-galaxies-which-fell-out-of-sight-horizon-due-to-cosmic-expansion), I am wondering, how long does it take for a galaxy or other space object, to disappear from our view from the Milky Way due to the expansion of the universe? Assume GN-z11 is our target object here, or some other notable distant object.

**Edit:** As @PM2Ring said in a comment, *"No galaxy that is observable today ever disappears (but does become increasingly redshifted."* So when does a target galaxy get so redshifted that we cannot see it anymore?

Comment: It depends on how you define "disappear". ;) From [this comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14336/are-there-any-galaxies-which-fell-out-of-sight-horizon-due-to-cosmic-expansion#comment25450_14338) on that page: *No galaxy that is observable today ever disappears (but does become increasingly redshifted)*. Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19910/16685 which has a helpful diagram.

Comment: Pm 2 Ring do you mean that there is no object far enough and receding fast enough to cross an event horizon? I was thinking it is possible.  Perhaps I should study again the famous article on "expanding confusion"...